# Dark Mode on Libre Office from Ubuntu repo

Tags: release-odin, libreoffice

How it's going on?

I was having troubles with Libre Office from Flathub, so installed the one available on the Ubuntu repository. That being said, Libre Office is not absorbing elementaryOS dark mode. Do some of you guys know which package should I install from the Ubuntu repository so that Libre Office can absorb the dark mode?

Ty!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following text

```
[Settings]
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1
```

into the file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` (that tilde means your home directory). If the file doesn't exist, you can create it. This should tell all applications to prefer dark themes.

Answer (score 0):

I understand, and can be wrong, that just the elementary apps can directly get the color toggle between light and dark with elementary original theme. Maybe firefox will do that soon, but is entirely app developers decision.

What I have done is change the gtk theme, choosing one dark from gnome-look.org, with the addition of qt5ct I could get certain level of uniformity across most applications, with the exception of flatpack apps installed from appcenter.